# images upload in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have installed a fresh setup for Magento 1.9 and I have a problem in uploading an image in the product as there is no option to upload an image.

See screenshot
https://prnt.sc/stfde4 there is no option for upload button

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but Magento 1.9 is coming to end of life very soon, so you may want to switch to Magento 2

Comment: Try this html5 plugin: https://www.mavenecommerce.com/2016/10/18/magento-html5-uploader/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento V1 uses Flash to upload images and Flash as is being deprecated in browsers across the board. You can enable flash on a site by site basis in different browsers as detailsed below:

Edge
 - Select the information icon icon, small 'i' in a circle next to the website's address in the address bar to bring up the drop-down as shown and click on Allow Adobe Flash.
- Under Website Permissions, ensure the slider for Adobe Flash is moved to the On position as shown.

IE
- Select the Settings cog light gray outline gear icon at the top right-hand side of the window and select Manage add-ons from the menu that appears.
- Make sure Show: on the lower-left hand side has All add-ons selected and highlight Shockwave Flash Player in the list. Then click Enabled to enable it.

Firefox
- Navigate to a page that uses Adobe Flash and a new add-on icon of a browser window with a blue dot on the top rightwill appear next to it in the address bar. Click that icon to open the menu. Select the checkbox next to Remember this decision if you want to continue to allow Flash to run on this site in the future. Then click Allow.

Chrome
- Click the information icon gray circle with a small 'i' icon or the lock icon green lock icon in the website addressbar at the top left. From the dropdown that appears, select Site Settings.
- From the menu that appears, next to Flash, select Allow.

References: https://www.umass.edu/it/support/support-center/howenableflashyourwebbrowser